# I've got problem with parsing data from html using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, attributeerror

I am trying to download the list of matches from the link: https://www.vitisport.cz/index.php?clanek=quicktips&sekce=fotbal&lang=pl .I keep getting an error showing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jakub/PycharmProjects/proj2/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    rows = table.find('td').find_all('tr')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Can I ask you for advice?

Here is my code:
main.py

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from match import Match

matches= []
source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.vitisport.cz/index.php?clanek=quicktips&sekce=fotbal&lang=pl").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "tabulkaquick"})[0].find('table')
rows = table.find('td').find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all("td")
    matches.append(Match(cols[0].datetime,cols[1].text,cols[2].text,cols[3].int,cols[4].text,cols[5].text,cols[6].text))
with open('matches_list.txt','w') as f:
    for match in matches:
        print(match)
        f.write(f"{match.date},{match.host},{match.guest},{match.goals1st},{match.goals2nd},{match.type},({match.index})\n")
```

and match.py:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Match:
    def __init__(self, date, host, guest, goals1st, goals2nd, type, index):
        self.date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d.%m.%Y')
        self.host = host(str)
        self.guest = guest(str)
        self.goals1st = goals1st(int)
        self.goals2nd = goals2nd(int)
        self.type = type(str)
        self.index = index(float)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.date
        return self.host
        return self.guest
        return self.goals1st
        return self.goals2nd
        return self.type
        return self.index
```

Comment: The error means that table (line 9, main.py) has value None, which means the previous line, where you initialized it, returned None. Inspect the results of each call on line 8 (it's several of them together) with a debugger or print statements to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are getting it, the table returns `None`, so you cannot parse it, try this you will get the table

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "tabulkaquick"})
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```